# android - start animating a view immediately

Tags: android, android-animation, visibility

i am making an android app and i am a newbie in development.

I created a startup animation for the app, using the app icon that is scaled from O% size to 100% size and rotated at the same time. This works allright. But i have a problem with it. In xml, the view visibility is set to gone initially. In code, i call `image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` and then `image.startAnimation(iconAnimation)` . But the result is that i can see a flash of the ImageView before it starts animating, for like half a second or so. You can see the gif.

Gif:
[see the gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2mXL.gif)

Can you help me with this? Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // here 
                    image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    image.startAnimation(imageAnim);
                    //also found this somewhere, didn't help.
                    image.invalidate();
                }
            });
```

Layout xml:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:text="Kytky"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/welcome_text"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/welcome_image"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Comment: Try: `android:visibility="invisible"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use value animator instead, You can hack through the animation

```
    imageView.setPivotX(viewCenterX);
    imageView.setPivotY(viewCenterY);
    imageView.setScaleX(0);
    imageView.setScaleY(0);

    final FloatEvaluator scaleEvaluator = new FloatEvaluator();
    final FloatEvaluator rotationEvaluator = new FloatEvaluator();
    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1f);
    valueAnimator.setDuration(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
    valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            float fraction = animation.getAnimatedFraction();
            float scale = scaleEvaluator.evaluate(fraction, 0f, 1f);
            float rotation = rotationEvaluator.evaluate(fraction, 0f, 360f);
            imageView.setScale(scale);
            imageView.setRotation(rotation);
        }
    });
    valueAnimator.start();
```

Start one more animator or use this same animator to slide the logo up. Using this animators you will have full control over your animation.

Answer (score 1):

you can switch the view visibility when the animations starts

```
imageAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
      @Override
      public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }

      @Override
      public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

      }
    });

    image.startAnimation(imageAnim);
```

the blink happens because the view visibility far from starting the animations, so in the first frame it will have its real size, and after that starts the animation

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with alpha as well...make it visible and set alpha to minimum value than set alpha gradually to maximum value with in handler.